# Bayesian Statistics - Basic question about prior

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I try to get an understanding of bayesian statistics. My intuition tells me that in the expression for the posterior

$$p(\vartheta|x) = \frac{p(x|\vartheta)p(\vartheta)}{\int_\Theta p(x|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta}$$

the term $p(\vartheta)$ is the marginal distribution of the likelihood-function $p(\vartheta,x)$. It is obtained by
$$p(\vartheta)=\int_X p(\vartheta|x)p_X(x)dx$$
where $p_X(x)$ should be the marginal distribution of the Observable data. Does that make sense?

To this point it makes sense with this example:
Offering somebody a car insurance without knowing the person's style of driving (determined by $\vartheta \in \Theta$) to feed some statistical model, we still can make use of the nation's car-crash statistics as our prior, which is a pdf on $\Theta$. That would be the marginal distribution of the "driving styles" across the population.

Maybe I am just oversimplifying here, because my resources did not mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bayesian way of thinking, the prior distribution has no dependence on the data, so trying to get $p\left(\vartheta\right)$ by integrating over $x$ is an incorrect way to think about it. The distribution $p\left(\vartheta\right)$ exists first -- it represents what you believe about the $\vartheta$ parameter (i.e., which values it is more or less likely to have) before having seen any data. Then, you observe $x$ and update your beliefs to the conditional distribution $p\left(\vartheta\,|\,x\right)$.

But from which distribution do you observe $x$? This distribution will be different depending on what $\vartheta$ is. So, it only makes sense to talk about $p\left(x\right)$ as an expectation over different $\theta$ values, as in the denominator of the Bayesian update.

Comment: Can I say, that I treat it, AS IF it was related to the data and apply bayes theorem to it?

Comment: If you say that, it defeats the purpose of doing Bayesian statistics at all -- the value of this approach is that it allows you to impose a distribution on the unknown parameter that is _not_ related to the data (hence why it is called a "prior"). Bayes' rule is used to update the distribution of belief on the parameter. In order to write it your way, you need to know $p\left(x\right)$, but the whole point is that the _only_ way for you to represent this distribution is by integrating over the prior.

Comment: So I start with a prior that is just an arbitrary belief about the distribution and then condition it on the observed data. And this update-step is in the fraction with the normalizing integral by applying bayes-theorem.

Comment: Yes, you could say that. If your prior is really completely arbitrary, i.e., you have _no_ idea about the parameter, you should use a "non-informative prior." For example, if the prior distribution is normal, you can give it infinite variance. But usually you at least have a rough idea of where the parameter should be. For example, if the prior is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, you can think of it as saying that the true parameter is 95% likely to be within $\mu \pm 2\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  you to change the point of view in order to enter in the bayesian way of thinking:

Think at the posterior in the following way:

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \pi(\theta)\times p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$$

Where the prior is a distribution that include all the information you have on your parameter multiplied (corrected) by the likelihood which include all the information given by the data.

As per the fact that $\pi(\theta)\times p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$ could not be a distribution (because its integral could be $\ne 1$) you have to normalize it multiplying the previous product by a constant.

I think that [this basic topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806844/what-is-relationship-between-beta-and-binomial-distributions-in-bayesian-inferen) could be useful for you.